# How to bind vue click event with vue tables 2 (JSX)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx, vue-tables-2

Using https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2, with Vue version 2, I can't seem to bind the click event on JSX (on templates->edit):

```
var tableColumns = ['name', 'stock', 'sku', 'price', 'created_at']
var options = {
  compileTemplates: true,
  highlightMatches: true,
  pagination: {
    dropdown: true,
    chunk: 10
  },
  filterByColumn: true,
  texts: {
    filter: 'Search:'
  },
  datepickerOptions: {
    showDropdowns: true
  },
  templates: {
    edit: function (h, row) {
      return <button v-on:click={this.showItem(row.id)} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
    },
    delete: function (h, row) {
      return <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
    }
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'ItemList',
  data: function () {
    return {
      options: options,
      columns: tableColumns
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showItem: function (id) {
      console.log(id)
    }
  }
}
```

Changed to JSX `on-click`, but Vue cannot recognize that.
`.babelrc` already has:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-vue-jsx"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I learned this the hard way, since I'm not familiar with JSX when I was looking for the solution for this. However, don't use **onClick**, but **on-click** instead.

Here you go:

**ES6**

```
edit: (h, row) => {
  return <button on-click={ () => this.showItem(row) } class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
},
```

**ES5:**

```
edit: function (h, row) {
  return <button on-click={ this.showItem.bind(this, row) } class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
},
```