# On click function in vue-tables-2 throwing fns.apply is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I'm currently implementing vue-tables-2 (first time) and I've set up a template to show an icon that will fire an event when clicked. However, I'm getting an error that I'm not sure where it's deriving from. The error is the following.

```
Uncaught TypeError: fns.apply is not a function
at HTMLAnchorElement.invoker (vue.esm.js:1821)



templates: {
      edit: function (h, row) {
        return <a href='javascript:void(0);' on-click='$parent.editSchedulesBtn(${row.id})' ><i class='fa fa-pencil-square fa-2x' aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      }
```

The function code itself is as follows.

```
editSchedulesBtn: function (rowId) {
  console.log(rowId)
}
```

I have found this stackoverflow question have tried implementing it, but no success --> [How to bind vue click event with vue tables 2 (JSX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817327/how-to-bind-vue-click-event-with-vue-tables-2-jsx)

Thanks for all assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems:

A syntax error:

Instead of

```
 edit: function (h, row) {
        return <a href='javascript:void(0);' on-click='$parent.editSchedulesBtn(${row.id})' ><i class='fa fa-pencil-square fa-2x' aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      }
```

Should be:

```
 edit: function (h, row) {
        return <a href='javascript:void(0);' on-click={this.$parent.editSchedulesBtn(row.id)}><i class='fa fa-pencil-square fa-2x' aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      }
```

Secondly, the `this` context inside the function refers to the root vue instance, as stated in the docs:

> In addition a this context will be available, which refers to the root
>   vue instance.

So the `$parent` is obsolete. You might even have to use `$children` or `$refs`, depending on your app structure (Explore the tree using the chrome dev tools and you will find the exact "address").

Thirdly, when binding an event with `jsx` you should not call the method directly, but use the `bind` method instead (As explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817327/how-to-bind-vue-click-event-with-vue-tables-2-jsx) you have attached):

```
on-click={this.editSchedulesBtn.bind(this, row.id)} // See the aforementioned answer for ES6 syntax
```

As an aside, since Vue introduced scoped slots in v2.1, it is best to [use those](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#scoped-slots) rather than jsx, which requires compilation, and is generally more cumbersome to deal with.